# use facebook api authentication on the devlopment server

Tags: facebook

I use the facebook authentication on my site,
and it works great on the server

but I can't login when I run the site localy,
so I need to deploy on the server every time I want to test it.

is there a way to login on the local-dev-server?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you probably didn't change the Site URL in your facebook application settings (edit your app->Website->Site URL) to your localhost URL.

The best solution here is to create a new development facebook app and set your localhost URL there.

Comment: +1. I would create a new application, maybe `my_app_local` and test locally using that App.